# Check if Error Frame is present on Communication matrix

Tags: testing, capl

Is there any way to seek through a capl test module if there is an error on the trace ( on the communication mainframe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set up on events for

```
on errorFrame
{
}
```

for parallel monitoring of your CAN communication (during your CAPL/XML test module is running).

Using it you should get plenty documentation in CANoe help (F1).